# Saving records to database using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I have to save a record to H2 database using threads.

This is the method in my database class that's used to save a category, a class that has name and description, into database:

```java
public static void saveNewCategory(Category newCategory, Connection connection){
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO CATEGORY(NAME, DESCRIPTION) VALUES(?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1, newCategory.getName());
        ps.setString(2, newCategory.getDescription());

        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my thread class which is supposed to implement that principle and save it into database using threads

```java
public class SaveCategoryThread implements Runnable{

    private static Connection connectToDatabase;
    private Category category;

    public SaveCategoryThread(Category categoryC) {
        category=categoryC;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            openConnectionWithDatabase();

            Database.saveNewCategory(category,connectToDatabase);

        } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeConnectionWithDatabase();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void openConnectionWithDatabase() throws IOException, SQLException {
        if (Database.activeConnectionWithDatabase) {
            try {
                wait();
                System.out.println("Connection is busy");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        connectToDatabase = Database.connectToDatabase();
    }

    public synchronized void closeConnectionWithDatabase() {
        try {
            Database.disconnectFromDatabase(connectToDatabase);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

And this is how I am executing it in my JavaFX class which takes user input

```java
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
es.execute(new SaveCategoryThread(category));
```

But it's not working, no errors or anything, but the result isn't saved into the database.

Comment: Please include the complete implementation of the `Database` class in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is the `wait` / `notifyAll` code.

You are waiting / notifying on `this`.  In this context that will be the `Runnable` instances that you are submitting to the `ExecutorService`.  They are all different objects.  So the `notifyAll` notifications will not be going to reach the `Runnable` objects that are waiting.

---

But I think that I should point out that the *strategy* that you are trying to implement here is (basically) wrong.  It looks like you are trying to use one database connection and share it between multiple threads.  Effectively, all database INSERT operations will be single-threaded; i.e. no parallelism in the database operations.

If you want parallelism, use multiple connections managed by an off-the-shelf JDBC connection pool.  That will also avoid the overhead of opening and closing database connections for each INSERT ... as your current implementation *might* be doing.  (We can't see the relevant code.)

But if you want *good insert performance*, don't do transactions that consist of a single INSERT statement.  Instead use JDBC's batch mechanism or multi-row INSERT statements.

Answer (score 1):

## `DataSource`

I agree with the [Answer by Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70887918/saving-records-to-database-using-threads-java), except for the part advocating the use of a connection pool. IMHO, the need for connection pooling is commonly oversold, and the risks/issues underplayed. As for his main point, I concur: You are likely headed for trouble in trying to share a `Connection` object. I got apprehensive just seeing `static Connection`, as there should be no need to ever keep a `Connection` around via a `static`.

Instead of focusing on passing around a `Connection` object, I suggest you instead pass around a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object. A `DataSource` holds all the information needed to connect to a database. Or, if you decide on connection pooling, a `DataSource` object can be the front door to accessing that pool. Either way, using a `DataSource` is simple, as it mainly consists of the method `getConnection`, returning a `Connection` object.

You can hard-code a `DataSource` object with the database info such as database server address, database username & password, and so on. Or you can externalize those details to be configured at runtime by an administrator in a [directory/naming service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service) like an [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) server, or in a [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) server. Use [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) in Java to obtain the externalized `DataSource` object.

For example, with the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)), use the bundled implemantion of `DataSource`, [`org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource`](https://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcDataSource.html). Here is some code showing how to hard-code the `DataSource` info.

```java
public javax.sql.DataSource configureDataSource() {
    org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource ds = Objects.requireNonNull( new JdbcDataSource() );  // Implementation of `DataSource` bundled with H2.
    ds.setURL( "jdbc:h2:/path/to/database_file;" );
    ds.setUser( "scott" );
    ds.setPassword( "tiger" );
    ds.setDescription( "An example database showing how to use DataSource." );
    return ds ;
}
```

Keep that `DataSource` object around for later use. This object merely holds connection info (or access to a connection pool). Pass to your JDBC code.

By the way, a big tip for you: Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close your resources such as `Connection`, `Statement`, and `ResultSet`.

I also recommend making a habit of properly terminating your SQL statements with a SEMICOLON (`;`).

Add a second `catch`, in addition to `SQLException`, for the more specific exception also thrown by `DataSource#getConnection`: [`SQLTimeoutException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/SQLTimeoutException.html). This exception is for when the driver has determined that the timeout value specified by the `setLoginTimeout` method has been exceeded.

```java
public void saveNewCategory( Category newCategory, DataSource ds ){
        String sql = "INSERT INTO CATEGORY( NAME, DESCRIPTION ) VALUES( ?, ? ) ;";
        try (
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection() ;
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql );
        ) {
            ps.setString( 1, newCategory.getName() );
            ps.setString( 2, newCategory.getDescription() );
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch ( SQLTimeoutException e ) {
            … 
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            … 
        }
}
```

Notice in the code above how the try-with-resources syntax will automatically close both the `Connection` and `PreparedStatement` objects, if they are successfully opened. We do not want to leave that `Connection` object left open any longer than is necessary.

## Executor service

As for using concurrency with threads, using a `DataSource` probably simplifies your code significantly.

Early on, define a `ExecutorService` object, and keep it around. If you want a single task to be executed at a time, use a single-threaded service. If you want concurrent tasks, use a service backed by a pool of threads.

Either way, use `Executors` utility class to obtain a `ExecutorService` as seen in your code. Keep this `ExecutorService` object around, for repeated use.

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
…
```

When you are ready to persist one of your `Category` objects, define a task and pass to the executor service. As your code shows, the task is defined as a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or a `Callable`.

But the name `SaveCategoryThread` you chose for your `Runnable` task suggests you are thinking about managing threads. That is not what a `Runnable` is about. The `Runnable` is the work to be done, without regard for threads. A `Runnable` can be executed on the same thread, as is appropriate to some situations. So the **`Runnable` is *not* in charge of threads**. Managing threads is the job of the `ExecutorService`.

```java
public class SaveNewCategoryTask implements Runnable {
    // Member fields. 
    DataSource dataSource;
    Category newCategory ;

    // Constructor
    public SaveNewCategoryTask ( Category newCategory , DataSource dataSource ) {
        this.newCategory = newCategory ; // Remember the passed argument.
        this.dataSource = dataSource ; // Remember the passed argument.
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        saveNewCategory( this.newCategory , this.dataSource ) ;
    }
}
```

Notice how our `Runnable` is no longer tracking connections or exceptions. All the database exchange details are contained within the `saveNewCategory` method. It is generally best to keep the `Runnable` task class as simple as possible. Its job is to simply hold info until needed, when its `run` method is eventually executed.

Usage:

```
// Retrieve that `DataSource` object you established early on in your app’s lifecycle.
DataSource ds = … retrieve existing object … ;
// Retrieve the `ExecutorService` object you established early on in your app’s lifecycle.
ExecutorService es = … retrieve existing object … ;
es.submit( new SaveNewCategoryTask( newCategory , ds ) ) ;
```

I am not entirely sure of your intent with using `wait` and `notifyAll`. It seems you are trying to manage simultaneous access to a single `Connection` object. As Stephen C explains in other Answer, that is basically a wrong approach, fraught with peril. Hopefully I have shown that such an approach is also unnecessary and needlessly complicated.

## JavaFX

All the above discussion was aimed at Java in general.

But you mentioned [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX). JavaFX has [its own concurrency utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm). I am not familiar with those. Hopefully the above code helps establish some general concepts and guidelines, but you may need to modify to work properly with JavaFX.